# How can I test update using querydsl?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to test update using custom repository with querydsl.
But it fails because the data is not updated. I tried flushing after I call repository function, but it did not work.
I think it is related with some kind of Entity manager problem, but I don't know exactly since I'm new to Spring.

**Repository code :**

```java
    @Override
    public Long updateNotice(String noticeId, Notice noticeInfo) {
        UpdateClause<JPAUpdateClause> updateBuilder = queryFactory.update(notice);

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(noticeInfo.getTitle())) {
            updateBuilder.set(notice.title, noticeInfo.getTitle());
        }

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(noticeInfo.getContents())) {
            updateBuilder.set(notice.contents, noticeInfo.getContents());
        }

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(noticeInfo.getTheme())) {
            updateBuilder.set(notice.theme, noticeInfo.getTheme());
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(Integer.toString(noticeInfo.getState()))) {
            updateBuilder.set(notice.state, noticeInfo.getState());
        }

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(noticeInfo.getLocation())) {
            updateBuilder.set(notice.location, noticeInfo.getLocation());
        }

        updateBuilder.set(notice.startDate, noticeInfo.getStartDate());
        updateBuilder.set(notice.endDate, noticeInfo.getEndDate());
        updateBuilder.set(notice.modiDate, LocalDateTime.now());

        Long count = updateBuilder
                .where(notice.noticeId.eq(noticeId))
                .execute();

        return count;
    }
```

**Test code :**

```java
    @Test
    public void updateNoticeTest() {

        //given
        Notice titleNotice = Notice.builder()
                .title("Update notice")
                .startDate(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 10, 11, 00, 00, 00))
                .endDate(LocalDateTime.of(2021, 12, 12, 00, 00, 00))
                .build();

        List<Notice> notices = noticeRepository.findAll();
        String id = notices.get(1).getNoticeId();
        Notice notice = notices.get(1);
        log.info(notice.toString());

        //when

        Long result = noticeRepository.updateNotice(id, titleNotice);
        noticeRepository.flush();

        //then
        Notice res = noticeRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No such notice with id " + id));
        log.info(res.toString());
        assertThat(res.getTitle()).isEqualTo("Update notice");
    }
```

**Test configuration:**

```
# Datasource settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=


# set jpa
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace


# set log
logging.level.root=info

# set page option
# 1-based
spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true
# page size = 10
spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size=10
spring.data.web.pageable.max-page-size=1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Flushing doesn't help because it writes changes collected by the `EntityManager` out to the database. But the EM didn't collect any changes since you used an update statement which doesn't update the 1st level cache which basically is the EM.

The `findById` will return the old instance already in the 1st level cache from some earlier interaction, possibly from storing them in the first place.

In order to fix this you should empty the 1st level cache by calling [`EntityManager.clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--)

Comment: way underrated answer. Spent two hours on this, completely missed looking critically at the 'repository.flush()' part after implementing JPAUpdateClause. Changed to clear EM and works perfectly. Thanks!